# When using truncate I get the following error "index 113257 out of string"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, truncate

What does this error mean? Here is the line of code that generates it

```
 apts[ndex] = truncate(results[ndex][:public_note].to_s,:length => 300)
```

results is an array of activerecord objects

Comment: Can you paste more code? We need the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. apts[ndex] is a activerecord object, what I wanted to do was assign the truncated value to apts[ndex][:public_note].

I have no idea what the error message meant, can anyone shed some light on it?